# Mensagem: "Esta pergunta foi fechado. Não serão aceitas mais respostas"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Não, o título desta pergunta não está errado. Bem... Na verdade ele está sim e é exatamente este o propósito desta pergunta.

Quando você está visualizando uma pergunta qualquer e ela é fechada enquanto você a visualiza, surge uma barra marrom no topo com o seguinte texto:

> Esta pergunta foi fechado. Não serão aceitas mais respostas.

O erro de concordância é óbvio: "pergunta foi fechado" ao invés de "pergunta foi fechada".

---

[Editado, meses depois] - Também esbarrei com esta daqui, com o mesmo tipo de erro de concordância:

> Esta pergunta foi excluído. Não serão aceitas mais respostas.

Comment: Basicamente, a string no sistema é "Esta pergunta foi {mensagem}. ...". E a mensagem vem no masculino, porque o status "fechado" é usado em outros lugares no sistema. Vou ter que ver com os devs

Comment: @Gabe Mesmo assim parece estranho que o termo seja "fechado", no masculino, já que a única coisa que pode ser fechada no site são *perguntas*.

Comment: [Link da string em questão no sistema de tradução](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/40271467). No caso de "fechado", isso já deve estar corrigido, pois eu alterei recentemente todas as ocorrências de "fechado" para "fechada" (ver meu comentário acima). Já o "excluído" eu tenho receio de alterar, talvez seja usado em outros contextos também –  consertaria um lado e estragaria outro.